# Center image view on rotate

Tags: android, image, center

I have an image view with an image and it looks find when the phone is portrait. When I turn it landscape, it rotates, however, the image isn't centered anymore. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than making a new folder and xml file and all that, I simply did

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

on my image view and when I rotate the device, the image stays centered.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `layout-land` directory in your `res` folder. And copy your layout files with landscape orientation. That should do it.